# intuition behind the definition of Dirichlet function

Tags: limits, functions, intuition

I've seen two definitions of Dirichlet function which are as follows: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}  0   &\text{ if } x\text{ is irrational }\\
          1  &\text{ if } x \text{ is rational.}\end{cases}$$

and the second one :

$$\lim_{k \to \ \infty }(\lim_{j \to \ \infty }cos(k!\pi x)^{2j})$$

for integers $k,j$

why such a simple function can be shown as double limit and why should I expect a simple $0$ or $1$ to be the answers of the given limit?
I know some properties of  Dirichlet function, for example I know it's not Riemann integrable or it does not have any limit, but I have no idea about the second definiton and up to now could't find any reason for that, what is the motivation behind that and how it can be "fully" derived?

Comment: If $x$ is rational, for $k$ large, $k! x$ will be an integer since $k!$ will take care of the denominator for $x$ and you'll be left with a multiple of $pi$ inside $\cos$, giving $1$ after raising it to the $2j$. For $x$ irrational, $k!x$ is never integral, so $\cos^2$ will be strictly between $0$ and $1$. Raising that to the $j$ for $j$ large will give you something arbitrarily close to $0$. I think this is right.. I haven't quite fully woken up yet today.

Comment: actually I want to know what was the first person who introduced such definition thinking about,the definition is interesting in its own way